# Python Kafka - max messages in file

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

Is there any way to get just one message, save it to a file, and terminate the script?
I'd like to loop this over so that it saves me each message to a separate file.
From the cmd level, I had a parameter:

```
max-messages 1
```

but in python I haven't found anything like this. Code below:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import sys
import datetime

now_day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(now_day)

directory = "D:/Kafka/test/files_" + now_day + "/earnix_topic_"
print(directory)

now_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
print("Current date: " + now_datetime)

full_path = directory + now_datetime + ".txt"
print(full_path)

bootstrap_servers = ['prod-kafka-wrk01:0000','prod-kafka-wrk02:0001','prod-kafka-wrk03:0003']

# Define topic name from where the message will recieve
topicName = 'notify.products.client.topic'

consumer = KafkaConsumer(topicName,  group_id ='groupABasdsadC',bootstrap_servers = bootstrap_servers)

# Read and print message from consumer
for msg in consumer:
   file = open(full_path, "w+")
   file.write(str(msg.value))
   file.close()

sys.exit()
```

Comment: your consumer will emit one message at a time regardless, what is the issue with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent `sys.exit()` into the loop if you want to consume only one record and end the script

Answer (score 0):

You implicitly use the `__iter__()` or `__getitem__()` method on the consumer if you use:

```
for msg in consumer:
  #do something...
```

You can use the built-in `next()` function that will also make use of the `__iter__()` method:

```
msg = next(consumer)
```

For more on python iterable types, see: https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/Iterables.html

Or you can ignore the iterator adapter and use the `poll(...)` method, that will return a smaller list of messages that are currently in the topic. See https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html